# I'm trying to work with Graphics and draw some Rectangles

Tags: java, swing, class, object, graphics

Hello i'm trying to learn Graphics in java and at the same time Classes and Objects. My goal now is to make a programm that contains different classes with Rectangles or Circles and then I want to use those Rectangles and Circles in other classes and change their parameters like size, color and position to draw some kind of Pattern.

My problem right now is that I can make a rectangle and I think I can even make a second one, but i can't change parameters of it (Color, size and position) I tried adding variables to this part of code  `Rect rect = new Rect(int variables);` but it didn't work.

Normally I can solve easy problems like this but i really don't understand how classes and objects works in java if someone can give me some help would be great.

Here is my code

```
public class Main{


    public static void main(String[] args ) {

       Pattern.drawPattern();

    }
}



 import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class Rect extends JPanel{
        public static Color myColor = Color.RED;
        public static int myX = 10;
        public static int myY = 10;
        public static int myWidth = 200;
        public static int myHeight = 200;


        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(myColor);
            g.fillRect(myX, myY, myWidth, myHeight); 
        }
    }

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Pattern {

    public static void drawPattern() {

         JFrame window = new JFrame("test");
            window.setSize(1000, 800);
            window.setVisible(true);
            window.setResizable(false);
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            Rect rect = new Rect();
            Rect rect1 = new Rect();

            window.add(rect);
            window.add(rect1);

            Rect.myColor = Color.lightGray;

    }

}
```

Comment: See: [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/)

Comment: Hmm put everything in one class in IntelliJ works great. But maybe it helps if you trigger the repaint manually. Because thats what you need to do if you change the properties of the content you draw.

Comment: Please see update to answer. Please ask if any questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many problems here, but main ones I can see are:

- Over-use of static modifier in the Rect class. By using static fields, the Rect instances will not have their own unique state, their own color and position. Make all those fields private non-static (instance). If this causes compilation problems, fix it by not making the fields static but rather by not trying to access them from the class.
- Also give those fields  setter methods if you're going to want to change them outside the class. And getter methods if you want to query them
- You're ignoring the fact that a JFrame's contentPane uses BorderLayout by default. This layout will cover over previously added components by anything added next. If you need multiple components within this container, use a different layout
- But your main problem is that Rect should not extend JPanel, it should not be a *component* class but rather it should be a *logical* class.
- Instead create one class that extends JPanel and does all the drawing, and then give it multiple Rect instances to draw within its single paintComponent method. You could use an `ArrayList<Rect>` for this.
- Add this single drawing JPanel to the JFrame. Then there would be no need to change the JFrame's layout manager if you do this since BorderLayout would work nicely, allowing the drawing JPanel to fill the center of the JFreme.

Minor quibbles:

- Avoid giving your classes names that clash with common Java core classes, such as Pattern which is frequently used in Java regular expressions analysis
- Not sure why you even need the Pattern class since it doesn't do anything useful that couldn't be done in the main method.

For instance, Rect (or here named Rect2 to show it's different from your class) could look something like:

```
// imports here

public class Rect2 {
    private Color myColor = Color.RED;
    private int x = 10;
    private int y = x;
    private int width = 200;
    private int height = width;

    public Rect2() {
        // default constructor
    }

    public Rect2(Color myColor, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.myColor = myColor;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    // method used to allow the rectangle to be drawn
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(myColor);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public void setMyColor(Color myColor) {
        this.myColor = myColor;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    // more setters and some getters if need be

}
```

and the drawing JPanel something like:

```
// imports here

public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<Rect2> rectList = new ArrayList<>();

    // ..... more code

    public void addRect2(Rect2 rect) {
        rectList.add(rect);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // iterate through the rectList and draw all the Rectangles
        for (Rect2 rect : rectList) {
            rect.draw(g);
        }
    }

    // ...... more code

}
```

and it could be put into a JFrame like so....

```
Rect2 rectA = new Rect2();
Rect2 rectB = new Rect2();

rectB.setMyColor(Color.BLUE);
rectB.setX(300);
rectB.setY(300);

// assuming that the class's constructor allows sizing parameters
DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(1000, 800);
drawingPanel.addRect2(rectA);
drawingPanel.addRect2(rectB);

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main2");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane().add(drawingPanel);
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```